# Nested function scope variable

Tags: javascript, function, variables, nested, global

I'm using this doc : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp as an exemple.

I'm trying to get var name = snoopdog, outside the main function.

```js
function A(){
  function B(){
    name = "snoopdog";  
  }
  //Show snoopdog
  alert(name);
}

//Show nothing
alert(name);
```

Ok I tried to put the nested function inside a variable, still not working.

Comment: Your first and most awful error is at using w3schools for learning other language than html/css.

Comment: "I'm use w3schools" ... that's your first mistake, the second one is telling everyone you use it

Comment: Also, it is a _bad_ idea to define global variables in nested functions. Learn about scope, and functions, from a resource you can trust: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

Comment: Where `A()` called?, Where `B()` called?

Comment: _I tried to put the nested function inside a variable_, where you  do that?

Comment: "//Show nothing" Wrong, shows an error in the console, (in a case the name of `name` variable is not `name`, which refers to `window.name` property.)

Comment: fun facts: `window.name` can only be a string, and it's the only variable except the storages that survives reloading.

Comment: You're saying: "I'm trying to get var name = snoopdog, outside the main function.". But there's no declared `name` variable in your code. Please check that the posted code is the same you've tested. Also notice, that a scope can be accessed from inside, not from outside.

Comment: Maybe learn from more reliable sources, like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_scope).

Comment: Ah sorry my bad, it's actually an exemple, i forgot to add the A();

Comment: @Zakaria Acharki i tried something like var test = function B(){} at first

Comment: I ban w3c for Js then thanks guys xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global variables to the rescue

```
var name;
A();
alert(name) //shows snoopdog

function A(){
    B();

      function B(){
      name = "snoopdog";  
    }
    //Show snoopdog
    alert(name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you man, of course i called the function A(), thought it was implicit. This is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Using a var outside the main function, means you want to put it on the 'window' scope.

```
function A() {
    function B() {
        window.name = "snoopdog";  
    }
    //Show snoopdog
    alert(window.name);
}
//Show nothing
alert(window.name);
```